# What type of monostable multivibrator is this?

Tags: multivibrator

In the circuit description it said 4538b, but after googling the diagram of this IC, it seems there is no schmitt trigger on the input as it shows on the photo. Does CD14538BE work for this application. What is the best option? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look at the data sheet [here](http://www.nexperia.com/catcher/74HC_HCT4538.pdf?). Look at Figure 2 on page 3. Both inputs are Schmitt triggers, but the functionality is not shown on the active-low input since it is tied to Vcc.

Comment: What about this one?

Comment: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/76428.pdf?_ga=1.25166964.876401737.1476836941

Comment: @Baphomet - Oh, come on. Block diagram, upper right, page 2. RTFM, dude.

Comment: Ok calm down, I saw the bloody thing after I posted my question.